# JMeter Load Testing C# Rest APIs - Huge sample times

Tags: c#, rest, api, jmeter, load

I'm getting unusual issues when load testing my C# Rest APIs using JMeter Tool.

My API does a few database calls, it selects some data from one table, and returns it and manipulates it and inserts it into other tables.

If I run this API call on one instance, it executes in less than 3 seconds.

[1 user, no ramp up = < 3 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWOe1.png)

However, when running this same API call on 50 users on a 10 second ramp up time then I get the following results:

[50 users, 10 second ramp-up period = increased sample time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUASM.png)

Am I configuring JMeter incorrectly, or is something wrong within my API call which is causing this?

Comment: try with 50 second ramp up. see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group

Comment: @user7294900 - that works better, its up to around ~12 seconds now.. I tried 150 second ramp up which works much better.. but not sure what exactly i'm benefiting from this test

Comment: You need to provide more details, it can be caused by different reasons. Try to identify where the requests are delayed and why